# Centering image through css

Tags: center, css

I have the following CSS :

```
<style type="text/css">
body {background-color:#b32501;}
.roundcorner {
position:absolute;
    background-color: #000;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    border: 0px solid #000;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 350px;
    bottom:35%;
    right:500px;    
}


input
{
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; //For Safari, etc.
    -moz-border-radius: 5px; //For Mozilla, etc.
    border-radius: 5px; 
}
.centeredSplash {

    position:relative;
    width:100%; 
       height:100%; 
       background:url(coming-soon.png) center center no-repeat;

}

</style>
```

Following HTML:

```
<div class="centeredSplash">

    <div class="roundcorner">
        <input type="text" style="width:80%"></input>
    </div>

</div>
```

My basic requirement is that I have a 800x600 splash background with an empty space for HTML text box.

I need to have the splash background centered (no matter what resolution) and then I need to place my text box relative to the image so that it always display at that particular location.

With the above code I am able to achieve that but as soon as I reduce the size of my browser I notice that my text box starts to move away and lose its position, can anyone please help me out with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add

```
body {min-width: 800px;}
```

Working demo: 
[JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hLanC/1/)

Comment: Tried that and it still does not work, when I resize the browser window the text box moves to the left faster than the background image, losing its position.

Comment: That's beacause you didn't position you input right. Here is a working JSFiddle.

Comment: JSFiddle link missing